# C# - Clone a class into a dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic

With the class:

```
class C
{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

I can do this:

```
C c = new C();
dynamic D = new ExpandoObject();
D.a = c.a;
D.b = c.b;
```

But I'm looking for a way to do this automatically.

One way I found is to serialize the class to Json and deserialize it into a dynamic, but it is very slow.

This is to return 'limited' version of classes through an API; and I don't want to code the class building because that means that any updates will require the class building to be updated as well.

Comment: You could write a recursive reflection thing.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it; the frustrating part is that I remember some NuGet package doing something similar and I just can't find it anymore :)

Comment: Yes, it is! thanks Stanislav. We can close this question.